# Error Calling .jar from Excel VBA Using Call Shell()

Tags: vba, windows-defender

I'm trying to call a simple Java program from Excel VBA using the following command:

```
Call Shell("java -jar C:\TestMessage.jar arg0 arg1", vbNormalFocus)
```

I receive the error: "Run-time error'5': Invalid procedure call or argument" along with a taskbar notification: "Action Blocked; Your IT administrator caused Windows Defender Security Center to block this action."

I'm stuck, since I can use without issue:

```
Call Shell("notepad C:\gp.txt", vbNormalFocus)
```

Also, I can call the .jar from the command prompt using:

> java -jar C:\TestMessage.jar arg0 arg1

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Running notepad.exe and running some arbitrary .jar file are rather different things. Did you contact your IT administrator or looked into your Windows Defender Security Center to see what's blocking this action?

Comment: I guess I didn't understand that there would be a difference. I figured since I could run it from the command prompt and since I could run shell commands from VBA that the transitive property applied; I am mistaken. Figuring out who administers Win Defender will be a challenge and I can't see any settings from my end. I think I'll have to make VBA write to a file monitored by the jar file. Sorry for wasting your time and I very much appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
sTempBAT = "d:\tempLog.txt"
Set shellwindows = GetObject("new:9ba05972-f6a8-11cf-a442-00a0c90a8f39")
Set itemobj = shellwindows.Item()
itemobj.document.Application.ShellExecute sTempBAT, "", "", "open", 0
```

The above mentioned code will work to bypass the windows defender security to call the shell function
https://blog.sevagas.com/IMG/pdf/bypass_windows_defender_attack_surface_reduction.pdf